# 10 fold Cross Validation - function issues

Tags: r, function, cross-validation

I have created a function to perform 10 fold cross validation on a data set birthwt from library(MASS). The code within the function is doing what i want it to do. However, i want to use the values returned outside of the function but i cant access the mean_mrate variable outside of the function.

My code is:

```
library(MASS)

tenfold3 = function() {

  fold = 10
  end = nrow(birthwt)
  fold_2 = floor(end/fold)

  misclasrate=numeric()

  for(i in 1:10){

    df_i = birthwt[sample(nrow(birthwt)),] # random sort the dataframe birthwt

    tester = df_i[1:fold_2,]  # remove first tenth of rows - USE PREDICT ON THIS DATA
    trainer = df_i[-c(1:fold_2),]  # all other than the first tenth of rows - USE GLM ON THIS DATA

    #mod = glm(low~age,family=binomial,data=trainer)

    mod = glm(low~age+lwt+race+smoke+ptl+ht+ui+ftv,family=binomial,data=trainer)
    ypred = predict(mod,data=tester,type='response')
    ypred = trunc(0.5+predict(mod,data=tester,type='response')) # predicted values

    val_df = data.frame(trainer[,1],ypred) 
    names(val_df) = c('train','ypred')

    val_df$misclas = (val_df$train == val_df$ypred)
    misclasrate[i] = 1-sum(val_df$misclas) / nrow(val_df)
    mean_mrate = signif(mean(misclasrate),4)
    g = cbind(misclasrate[i],mean_mrate)
    return(mean_mrate)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function like this:

```
result = tenfold3()
```

The `result` variable will be equal to the `mean_mrate` variable inside the function.

Note that `return` breaks from the function and only the first iteration in the loop is executed. In addition, the more R-like style would be to wrap the contents inside the for loop in a function, and call the function 10 times using `lapply`.

Comment: Im a new R user. Could you please expand / show me sample code for how to do this?